# Why does Collections not sorting objects properly using timestamp?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, collections, comparator

When I have fetched objects from firebase realtime database into ArrayList then they are not sorted properly using Collections.sort() method. I have total **17** objects(posts) in my fetched ArrayList in which **2** objects are 1 month ago and rest **15** are under a month. Collection sorts properly these **15** objects but these **2** objects are added before **15** objects in sorting.

I am sorting these objects into ascending order of timestamp to show newer posts first and older at last. But very old posts (more than 1 month) are added before on sorting.

I have following PostModel class structure for Firebase

**PostModel Class:**

```
public class PostModel {
    public String title,description;
    public long timestamp;
    public PostModel(){}

    public PostModel(String title, String description,long timestamp) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }
}
```

I have passed timestamp into above class objects for insertion as **System.currentTimeMillis();** and sorted using following way.

```
Collections.sort(postsObjs, new Comparator<PostModel>() {
                            @Override
                            public int compare(PostModel o1, PostModel o2) {
                                return (int) (o2.timestamp - o1.timestamp);
                            }
                        });
```

Help me to sort my objects properly. Thanks

**Edit:** I have 17 objects in my ArrayList instead of 7 and rest is same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A compare method should return -1,0 or 1;

0: if (x==y)

-1: if (x < y)

1: if (x > y)

try this:

```
return Long.compare(o2.timestamp - o1.timestamp);
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. Is it efficient to use again compare inside compare method when objects keep increasing?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Long.compare(o1.timestamp, o2.timestamp)`?

Comment: @SophiaGray You'd have to compare the timestamps at some point anyway. The `Long.compare(...)` method simply does `return (x < y) ? -1 : ((x == y) ? 0 : 1);`. So you could either do that comparison manually or use a method which already does it for you. You should prefer the latter, not just because it makes your code more readable and has you using a well-tested method, but also because using the subtraction method (i.e. `return b - a`) has the _potential_ to overflow.

Comment: I can't understand what are you saying. Can you please modify my code in your answer. Thanks